# Battery Current - Refresh rate

Tags: android, linux-kernel, battery, batterylevel

I'm doing an application for a Samsung Tablet S10.1, and I need to have the battery current discharge values. I can obtain these values directly from the file "/sys/class/power_supply/battery/current_now", however they are updated only every 30s, which is not enough accurate for my app. I would like to know if there is any way to change this "time update rate" value.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried recompiling the battery driver(usually named fuel-guage or some such variant due to legacy reasons) in your Linux kernel source for the device and flashing the new kernel image?...

Comment: I haven't tried it actually, because I have no idea on how to do it. Could you please explain it better to me? Thanks a lot

Comment: A good place to start would be the [GalaxyTab10.1 forums on xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1050).